# Calculate NPS in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The net promoter score can have the values 0-10. It is divided in three groups:

Promoters = respondents giving a 9 or 10 score
Passives = respondents giving a 7 or 8 score
Detractors = respondents giving a 0 to 6 score

The score is calculated as the difference between the percentage of Promoters and Detractors.

Let's say we have the scores `[10, 9, 10, 6, 2, 5, 10]`.

This would give the score +14 (57% - 43%).

I wish I could count occurrences of a range in an array, if that would be possible I would do

```
total_count = array.size
promoters = array.count(9..10)
passives = array.count(7..8)
detractors = array.count(0..6)

promoters_perc = promoters.to_f / total_count * 100
detractors_perc = detractors.to_f / total_count * 100

score = promoters_perc - detractors_perc
```

How can I do this calculation?

Answer (score 3):

You can count all your metrics in hash:

```
arr = [10, 9, 10, 6, 2, 5, 10]
count = arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |e, memo|
  case e
  when 0..6 then memo[:detractors] += 1
  when 7..8 then memo[:passives] += 1
  when 9..10 then memo[:promoters] += 1 
  end
end

score = (count[:promoters] - count[:detractors]).to_f / arr.size * 100
=> 14.285714285714285
```

Shorter solution:

```
metrics = { promoters: 9..10, passives: 7..8, detractors: 0..6 }
count = metrics.each {|k, v| metrics[k] = arr.count {|e| v === e}}

score = (count[:promoters] - count[:detractors]).to_f / arr.size * 100
=> 14.285714285714285
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a some other ways of doing this as well, but for simplicity this should work.

```
array = [10, 9, 10, 6, 2, 5, 10]
total_count = array.size
promoters = array.count {|x| x > 8}
passives = array.count {|x| x > 6 && x <9}
detractors = array.count {|x| x < 7}

promoters_perc = promoters.to_f / total_count * 100
detractors_perc = detractors.to_f / total_count * 100

score = promoters_perc - detractors_perc
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more way to do this, code is self explanatory.

```
data = [10, 9, 10, 6, 2, 5, 10]

score_range = [promoters = (9..10), passives = (7..8), detractors = (0..6)]
#=> [9..10, 7..8, 0..6]
grouped = data.group_by {|i| score_range.select {|sr| sr.cover?(i)} }.to_h
#=> {[9..10]=>[10, 9, 10, 10], [0..6]=>[6, 2, 5]}
percentage = grouped.map {|(k),v| [k, (v.size  * 100.0/ data.size).round]}.to_h
#=> {9..10=>57, 0..6=>43}
nps = percentage[promoters] - percentage[detractors]
#=> 14
```